# How to download a VM image from GCP?

Tags: packer, gcp, virtualbox, images, vm

I do not see a download button. I would like to download a VM image that was created on GCP using Packer and I would like to run it locally in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get the actual GCE VM images.

But it's possible to [export the images to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) (as a `tar.gz` archive):

> If you need to move your Compute Engine boot disk data outside of your
>   Compute Engine project, you can export a boot disk image to Cloud
>   Storage as a `tar.gz` file.
>
> You can export a custom image as backup or for sharing by exporting
>   the image to Cloud Storage. This method is ideal for sharing
>   individual images with other projects that do not have access to your
>   images.

You can then download this `tar.gz` file and, I guess, create a VM image from it to run on your local machine. I imagine the process would contain steps similar  to those detailed in [Migrating VMs to Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/) and [Importing Boot Disk Images to Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image), only seen from your VirtualBox perspective instead of the GCE one.

These guides are making it easy to transfer VM loads **to** GCE. I guess they don't have incentives to do the same for transfers **from** GCE, which probably explains why there is no guide for it ;)